# Server hangs for while after 16000 requests

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am new to boost::asio. Trying to run

```
ab -n 20000 -c 5  -r http://127.0.0.1:9999/
```

Test gets stuck after 16000 request every time. But it does complete. Also I get lots of failed request.

What code is doing :

- A. Create Service
- B. Create Acceptor
- C. Bind and listen
- D. Create Socket
- F. Do async_connect
- G. In async_connect handler close socket. Create New One And do async_connect with same handler.

Code follows :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <memory>

// global variable for service and acceptor
boost::asio::io_service ioService;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor accp(ioService);

// callback for accept
void onAccept(const boost::system::error_code &ec, shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> soc) {
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    soc->send(boost::asio::buffer("In Accept"));
    soc->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
    soc.reset(new tcp::socket(ioService));
    accp.async_accept(*soc, [=](const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
            onAccept(ec, soc);
        });
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);
    try {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(9999));
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
        accp.open(endpoint.protocol());
        accp.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        accp.bind(endpoint);
        cout << "Ready to accept @ 9999" << endl;

        auto t1 = boost::thread([&]() { ioService.run(); });

        accp.listen(boost::asio::socket_base::max_connections);
        std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> soc = make_shared<tcp::socket>(ioService);

        accp.async_accept(*soc, [=](const boost::system::error_code &ec) { onAccept(ec, soc); });

        t1.join();
    } catch (std::exception &ex) {
        std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "] Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For completeness:

1. I changed my code as per @Arunmu
2. I used docker with linux because of socket problem suggested by @david-schwartz
3. Server never hangs now.
4. - Single Thread - 6045 req per sec
   - Threads - 5849 req per sec
5. Using async_write

Comment: Your code goes into infinite recursion until the stack exhaustion. The recursion in `onAccept` should be replaced with something correct

Comment: it is usual way for async programming. If i do not do that, there would not be any handler. It may look recursion but is not as async_accept returns immediately i.e. without calling anything.

Comment: In that case, put some limit on the recursion. Like the depth of calls.

Comment: If there is infinite recursion program should crash.

Comment: It depends on your OS and compiler. BTW, I did a quick search on asynchronous read and did not find any example with recursion. Please try doing you task in another way.

Comment: @GMichael you are very much mistaken. There is no recursion anywhere in this example.

Comment: @n.m. You say that `onAccept` calling `onAccept` with the same parameters is not a recursion. Correct?

Comment: @GMichael Check again on how it is called. It's being called as part of the lambda which is the handler passed to an async function. I think it's the code formatting that is causing the confusion.

Comment: @GMichael `onAccept` doesn't call `onAccept`. A lambda within `onAccept`  calls `onAccept`. `onAccept` doesn't call the lambda.

Comment: I bet you're running out of local sockets. What's your local socket port range? If you're on Linux, what does `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` output?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You hit the nail. Increasing the port range by `sysctl -w net.inet.ip.portrange.first=32768` and `sysctl -w net.inet.ip.portrange.hifirst=32768`  resolves temporary hang issue. You should provide that as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running out of local sockets. You should not be testing by generating all your load from a single IP address. (Also, your load generator should be smart enough to detect and work around this condition, but alas many aren't.)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's do things bit more correctly. I have changed the code to use the standalone asio instead of the boost one and use c++14 feature(s). With your raw code, there were lots of failures which I have reduced with my changes.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <system_error>
#include <chrono>

//global variable for service and acceptor
asio::io_service ioService;
asio::ip::tcp::acceptor accp(ioService); 

const char* response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n\r\n";

//callback for accept 
void onAccept(const std::error_code& ec, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> soc)
{
    using asio::ip::tcp;
    soc->set_option(asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));
    auto buf = new asio::streambuf;
    asio::async_read_until(*soc, *buf, "\r\n\r\n",
        [=](auto ec, auto siz) {
          asio::write(*soc, asio::buffer(response, std::strlen(response)));
          soc->shutdown(asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
          delete buf;
          soc->close();
        });
    auto nsoc = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(ioService);
    //soc.reset(new tcp::socket(ioService));
    accp.async_accept(*nsoc, [=](const std::error_code& ec){
      onAccept(ec, nsoc);
    });

}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    using asio::ip::tcp;
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);

    try{
        asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query( 
            "127.0.0.1", 
            std::to_string(9999)
        );

     asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve( query );
     accp.open( endpoint.protocol() );
     accp.set_option( asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address( true ) );
     accp.bind( endpoint );

     std::cout << "Ready to accept @ 9999" << std::endl;

     auto t1 = std::thread([&]() { ioService.run(); });
     auto t2 = std::thread([&]() { ioService.run(); });

     accp.listen( 1000 );

     std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> soc = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(ioService);

     accp.async_accept(*soc, [=](const std::error_code& ec) {
                                onAccept(ec, soc);
                              });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    } catch(const std::exception & ex){
      std::cout << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id()
        << "] Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
      std::cerr << "Caught unknown exception" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The main changes are:

1. Send a proper HTTP response.
2. Read the request. Otherwise you are just filling up you socket receive buffer.
3. Proper socket close.
4. Use of multiple threads. This was mostly required for Mac OS, not needed for linux.

Test command used: `ab -n 20000 -c 1 -r http://127.0.0.1:9999/`

On `Linux`, the test passed without any errors pretty quickly and without the use of additional threads for the `io_service`.

But, on `Mac` I was able to reproduce the issue i.e it was getting stuck after 16000 requests were processed. The process sample at that instant is:

```
Call graph:
    906 Thread_1887605   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 906 start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 1  [0x7fff868bc5c9]
    +   906 main  (in server_hangs_so) + 2695  [0x10d3622b7]
    +     906 std::__1::thread::join()  (in libc++.1.dylib) + 20  [0x7fff86ad6ba0]
    +       906 __semwait_signal  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8f44c48a]
    906 Thread_1887609
    + 906 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff8d0983ed]
    +   906 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 176  [0x7fff8d09afd7]
    +     906 _pthread_body  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 131  [0x7fff8d09b05a]
    +       906 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<main::$_2> >(void*)  (in server_hangs_so) + 124  [0x10d36317c]
    +         906 asio::detail::scheduler::run(std::__1::error_code&)  (in server_hangs_so) + 181  [0x10d36bc25]
    +           906 asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(asio::detail::scoped_lock<asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, std::__1::error_code const&)  (in server_hangs_so) + 393  [0x10d36bfe9]
    +             906 kevent  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8f44d21a]
    906 Thread_1887610
      906 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff8d0983ed]
        906 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 176  [0x7fff8d09afd7]
          906 _pthread_body  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 131  [0x7fff8d09b05a]
            906 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<main::$_3> >(void*)  (in server_hangs_so) + 124  [0x10d36324c]
              906 asio::detail::scheduler::run(std::__1::error_code&)  (in server_hangs_so) + 181  [0x10d36bc25]
                906 asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(asio::detail::scoped_lock<asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, std::__1::error_code const&)  (in server_hangs_so) + 263  [0x10d36bf67]
                  906 __psynch_cvwait  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8f44c136]

Total number in stack (recursive counted multiple, when >=5):

Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
        __psynch_cvwait  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        906
        __semwait_signal  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        906
        kevent  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        906
```

Only after providing the additional thread, I was able to get the test complete with below result:

```
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Completed 12000 requests
Completed 14000 requests
Completed 16000 requests
Completed 18000 requests
Completed 20000 requests
Finished 20000 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            9999

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        2 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   33.328 seconds
Complete requests:      20000
Failed requests:        3
   (Connect: 1, Receive: 1, Length: 1, Exceptions: 0)
Total transferred:      419979 bytes
HTML transferred:       39998 bytes
Requests per second:    600.09 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1.666 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.666 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          12.31 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0  30.7      0    4346
Processing:     0    1 184.4      0   26075
Waiting:        0    0   0.0      0       1
Total:          0    2 186.9      0   26075

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      0
  66%      0
  75%      0
  80%      0
  90%      0
  95%      0
  98%      0
  99%      0
 100%  26075 (longest request)
```

Stack trace of the thread which was probably stuck:

```
* thread #3: tid = 0x0002, 0x00007fff8f44d21a libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent + 10, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff8f44d21a libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000109c482ec server_hangs_so`asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::run(bool, asio::detail::op_queue<asio::detail::scheduler_operation>&) + 268
    frame #2: 0x0000000109c48039 server_hangs_so`asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(asio::detail::scoped_lock<asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, std::__1::error_code const&) + 393
    frame #3: 0x0000000109c47c75 server_hangs_so`asio::detail::scheduler::run(std::__1::error_code&) + 181
    frame #4: 0x0000000109c3f2fc server_hangs_so`void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<main::$_3> >(void*) + 124
    frame #5: 0x00007fff8d09b05a libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8d09afd7 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
    frame #7: 0x00007fff8d0983ed libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
```

This could probably an issue with `kqueue_reactor` implementation in `asio` or in the mac system itself (less probable)

**UPDATE:**
The same behaviour is observed with `libevent` as well. So, not an issue with `asio` implementation. It must be some bug in the kqueue kernel implementation. The issue is not seen with `epoll` on linux.

Comment: very nice research.

Comment: I do not get any failures after cleaning sockets. Even with 2 threads on mac process hangs for while around 16K req. Will update if i find something. Thanks  !!!

Comment: @VishalKumar The answer given by David is the correct one. Please accept that instead of this one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was due to Mac OSX's `net.inet.tcp.msl=15000`, as described here:

- https://rocketeer.be/blog/2014/04/benchmarking-on-osx-http-timeouts/
- https://kaiwern.com/posts/2022/08/11/benchmarking-http-server-stuck-at-16k-requests/

Closed connections were stuck in "TIME_WAIT" for a bit - using up available ephemeral ports - and clients were stuck in "SYN_SENT" waiting for ports to free up.